# Can't sign in to Android Studio on macOS

Tags: android, macos, google-chrome, android-studio, safari

When I click "sign in" in top right corner of Android Studio it opens browser when I enter Google Account credentials and everything goes well until last part where I end up with link like below

> http://localhost:50889/Callback?code=4/restofcode

Unfortunately browser don't know what to do with this and AS is still waiting for sign in.

I have Android Studio 3.0.1 and macOS 10.13.2.
I've tried to use Safari and Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to make this work is to use Google Chrome browser.